# How can I use a hidden field as a value in a SQL query with ASP.NET in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, httprequest

I'm writing a filter for a list of recordings and I'm trying to pass filter criteria into the url for the new page and then use that criteria to fill conditions in a SELECT query in MySQL.

However, I keep coming up with an issue that either no value enters the query and the table isn't filtered or it gives me a null value.

This is my first block of code where I request the criteria in the URL:

```
string Start;
string End;
string Agent;
string Campaign;
string Company;
string Phone;
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Start = Request["starttime"].ToString();
    string End = Request["endtime"].ToString();
    string Agent = Request["agent"].ToString();
    string Campaign = Request["campaign"].ToString();
    string Company = Request["company"].ToString();
    string Phone = Request["phone"].ToString();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindAgents();
    }
}
```

And this is the part of the code where I use the values in a query:

```
string hdnStartTime = Start;
    string hdnEndTime = End;
    string hdnAgent = Agent;
    string hdnCampaign = Campaign;
    string hdnCompany = Company;
    string hdnPhone = Phone;
    string SearchQuery = "SELECT custom_view.users.Full_Name as 'Agent', CompanyName as 'Company', phone_number as 'Phone Number', start_time as 'Call Date', length_in_min as 'Length', campaign_name as 'Campaign', status_combined.status_name as 'Disposition', location FROM custom_view.recording_log left join custom_view.custom_fields_data on custom_fields_data.lead_id = custom_view.recording_log.lead_id left join UtilityHiveDev.Company on CompanyID = custom_fields_data.custom_1 left join custom_view.users on custom_view.users.user = recording_log.user left join custom_view.campaigns on campaigns.campaign_id = recording_log.campaign_id left join custom_view.status_combined on status_combined.status = recording_log.status where start_time like '%" + hdnStartTime + "%' and end_time like '%" + hdnEndTime + "%' and custom_view.users.Full_Name like '%" + hdnAgent + "%' and campaign_name like '%" + hdnCampaign + "%' and CompanyName like '%" + hdnCompany + "%' and phone_number like '%" + hdnPhone + "%' order by start_time desc;";
```

I have tried several different ways and with this method nothing seems to pass into the variables from the HTTPRequest because there is no change in the table after filtering.

Comment: Don't use string-concatenation. Use parameters.

Comment: cant make any sense on what is the issue - and the code is split apart make it non valid what so ever.